# Calculo de rendimiento "Yield" en SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

estoy trabando con Power BI, con datos extraídos directamente de una base de datos mediante SQL sin embargo me gustaría extraer únicamente el porcentaje de piezas defectuosas de mi producto (Device_NG/Device_Total), sin embargo estos valores los extraigo de una misma columna y no se como realizar la consulta para organizar en una misma fila el calculo.

mi tabla es la siguiente:

```
Device_ID.......Lot_ID.........Label.................Occurrence
-----
red ................564645........device_Total.......522 
red ................564645........device_NG..........68 
red ................121212........device_Total.......451 
red.................121212........device_NG.........32
```

y lo que espero es obtener lo siguiente:

```
Device_ID.........Lot_ID..........Scrap%     
----
red....................564645........13.02 
red...................121212.........7.09
```

gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Estaras buscando un group by? que tipo de query haces para obtener esos datos? que son esos datos? como se calcula scrap?

Answer (score 1):

bienvenido a StackOverflow.

Podrías agrupar los datos y condicionar la división.

```
DECLARE @TEST TABLE (Device_ID nvarchar(20), Lot_ID int, Label nvarchar(20), Occurrence int)

INSERT INTO @TEST VALUES ('red',564645,'device_Total',522)
INSERT INTO @TEST VALUES ('red',564645,'device_NG',68 )
INSERT INTO @TEST VALUES ('red',121212,'device_Total',451 )
INSERT INTO @TEST VALUES ('red',121212,'device_NG',32)


SELECT 
     Device_ID
    ,Lot_ID
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN Label = 'device_NG' THEN Occurrence END) / CAST(NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN Label = 'device_Total' THEN Occurrence END),0) AS float) AS [Scrap%]
FROM @TEST
GROUP BY 
     Device_ID
    ,Lot_ID
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciono de maravilla, no tuve problema alguno.